# Scroll Multiple UICollectionView with one collectionview IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uicollectionview, collectionview

I am working on an application in which, I have UITableView and in each cell of uitableview i have uicollectionview scrolling horizontally.

Now, What I want is that: When I scroll one collectionview in any direction then all other collectionviews of my table should scroll accordingly in that direction.

I have tried using scrollview delegates but it is not working properly.

I am stuck in this issue. I have looked on internet but could not found anything yet.

Help needed! Thanks

Comment: But, if I understand your problem, you just need the collection view, why do you need the tableview?

Comment: actually I have multiple arrays filling collectionview. Because they all are of different types showing different data.
Thats why, according to my understanding i did it using both.

Comment: so in each row you have different data, like in the first row is an array of strings, in the second an array of numbers, etc ?

Comment: You should show the code you tried. In any case, it will only work for the visible cells because of cell reuse.

Comment: I want to have something like this:
http://connectedhome2go.files.wordpress.com/2010/05/motorola-medios-reference-design-guide-epg.jpg

When you scroll any collectionview then every other collectionview also scrolls.

Comment: I had to do something similar to the screenshot you just sent, and I do it using a tableview for the first column and a collectionView for the rest, and I linked the scrollview delegates for the vertical movement, and the horizontal scroll only scrolled the collection view. In your case I think independently of the content of the arrays you should use a collectionView with cell which can show the content of the arrays no matter what it is.

Comment: @diegomen: How did you manage to add the Time (scrolling above) because it also scrolls horizontally when one scrolls the collectionview.

Comment: I will post it as an aswer because it doesn't fit here :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok I've checked my code, what I do was: I got a tableView on the left side of the screen, and on the rest a UIScrollView, inside it I had on the top a view which width is equal to the collectionView.contentSize.width, and below that view, the collectionView, with its height equal to the screen height, and its width equal to its contentSize.width. After that, the ScrollView only scrolls horizontally, and the collectionView only scrolls vertically, so, when you scroll horizontally, the tableView stays, and the header view and the collection scrolls horizontally, and if you scroll vertically the header view stays fix, and the collection view and the tableView scrolls at the same time (you have to link their delegates).

[image]

That's what I do in the UIScrollViewDelegate

## pragma mark - UIScrollViewDelegate

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if (scrollView == _scrollView) {
        if (scrollView.contentOffset.y > 0  ||  scrollView.contentOffset.y < 0 ) {
            scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(scrollView.contentOffset.x, 0);
        }
    } else {
        _tableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, scrollView.contentOffset.y);
        _collectionView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, scrollView.contentOffset.y);
    }
}
```

The height of the cells of the tableView and the height of the cells of the collectionView was the same.

Answer (score 4):

You can coordinate two tableviews by declaring the containing view controller as a UITableViewDelegate and implementing the scrollView delegate method:

```
// say tv0 and tv1 are outlets to two table views
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if (scrollView == self.tv0) {
        self.tv1.contentOffset = self.tv0.contentOffset;
    } else if (scrollView == self.tv1) {
        self.tv0.contentOffset = self.tv1.contentOffset;
    }
}
```

To get the hang of it this first with a couple simple table views with the same length content.  You'll need to add conditional logic to handle when one view has a greater contentSize than the other.